# clearing dictionary entries and max entries of a dictionary

Tags: python

- Is there a way to delete all the entries of a dictionary without deleting the dictionary?
- Is there a limit to the number of entries that can be stored in a dictionary?

Comment: This is two questions - don't ask two questions in one question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes: `my_dict.clear()`.
2. No, it's limited by the addressable and available memory.

Comment: Technically, you could subclass `dict` and make your own that limited the number of entries.

Comment: So, if i have 2 GB of available RAM at any given period of time, and i load 1 GB of data into dictionary, process them and clear the entries from time to time, then there should be no problem right?

Comment: @rockluke: "1GB of data" isn't a precisely defined notion.  If you load data into a dictionary, this includes a format conversion.  How much memory the dictionary will need depends on how this conversion is performed.

Comment: [According to the Python docs](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) `if N objects are added to a dictionary, then N-1 are deleted, the dictionary will still be sized for N objects (at least) until another insertion is made.` So the dictionary will likely not be resized and it may be better to just rebind to another name, no?

Comment: @Pyson: If you delete items using `del`, the dictionary itself will
not be resized.  If you clear the dicitonary using `dict.clear()`,
though, the dictionary *will* be resized to its initial capacity of 8
entries (all this is CPython-specific).  Simply reassigning the name
does not have the desired effect in many situations.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I believe you. Thanks!

Comment: @Pyson: The behaviour is easy to observe even without looking at the source code – `sys.getsizeof()` returns the number of bytes currently occupied by the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

To clear a dictionary use the [`clear` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.clear):

```
>>> d = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
>>> d.clear()
>>> d
{ }
```

Generally the number of entries is limited only by the amount of memory you have.

Answer (score 1):

1) a way to delete all the entries of a dictionary without deleting the dictionary?

Simply point to empty dictionary

```
>>> x = {'1':'z', '2':'y'}
>>> id(x)
140265730038320
>>> x = {}
>>> id(x)
140265730045200
>>>
```

You will notice that x acts merely as an alias for the actual instance of dictionary.
You can simply point the 'x' to a empty dictionary instance later on.

Here you are simply changing the instance x is pointing to (140265730045200). The older instance (140265730038320) will be garbage collected if no one else is referring to it.

2) No there is no limit to number of entries that can be stored in a dictionary?

> It can hold unlimited number of dictionary elements limited only by
>   the memory requirements of your machine
>
> It is mutable and grows as you add more elements to it.

Comment: There are many situations where rebinding the name does not help – for example when the dictionary is passed into a function as a parameter, the function needs to change it in place.

Comment: Also note that `del x` deletes the name `x`, not the object it is pointing to.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Yes and you are completely right about it. I did think about it but after improving my response, I saw that you have already answered it. I did not want to repeat that in my answer as it would be redundant and ethically incorrect to do that :)

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I thought it does both and is equivalent. I will correct that

Comment: If you e.g. do `a = b = []; del b`, the list `b` points will not destroyed; `del` simply deletes the name and thereby decreases the reference count.